# Where does UFW (uncomplicated firewall) save command-line rules to?

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

You add a rule like this:

```
ufw allow 22/tcp
```

The rule is saved, and is applied even after reboot. But it's not written anywhere in `/etc/ufw`. Where is it saved to? (Ubuntu, using ufw as pre-installed.)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In my Ubuntu 11 server, the firewall rules are saved in `/lib/ufw/user.rules`

Comment: Bingo, thanks. There's also a user6.rules (which doesn't have all the rules I created, but otherwise looks similar).

Comment: user6.rules is for IP version 6 (ipv6) firewall rules.

Comment: Still correct in Ubuntu 14, thank you.

Comment: What a crazy location! I just spent 20 minutes looking for this :-(

Comment: I didn't, because I searched first on ServerFault :-) But I agree, it's anything but obvious...

Comment: ... also, these days, it's more common to find the active rules for _your_ system (as opposed to the original distro files) under `/etc/ufw` as [already answered here](https://serverfault.com/a/788489/133346) by @tivnet.

Answer (score 35):

**Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**

`/etc/ufw/user.rules`

**Debian 9**

`/etc/ufw/user.rules`

**In general, try:**

`locate user.rules`

Should output something like:

```
/etc/ufw/user.rules
/usr/share/ufw/user.rules
/usr/share/ufw/user.rules.md5sum
/usr/share/ufw/iptables/user.rules
```

Comment: It's recommended to run `updatedb` at least once before using `locate`.

Comment: @ccpizza On Ubuntu, at least, `updatedb` is run daily by `cron`. See `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`.

Comment: Still valid for Ubuntu 22.04 and Debian 11 as of 2022. Insane!

Answer (score 12):

I believe it's under `lib/ufw/rules[6].rules`

Answer (score 4):

In my version, 8.04 LTS Server the files are stored in `/var/lib/ufw` as `/var/lib/ufw/user.rules` and `/var/lib/ufw/user6.rules`.

Answer (score 3):

This should work on all Linux systems assuming a ".rules" suffix and residing beneath a directory named "ufw":

```
sudo find / -name "*.rules" -exec ls -l {} \; | grep ufw
```

Using the "ls -l" shows that some of them are links to others, and which ones have been updated most recently (implying they are active?)

Comment: Assuming that Debian/Ubuntu have been consistently implementing their usual configuration for `ufw` as well, there is some logic implied: _original_ (raw from the distro) files should be under `/usr/share/ufw/`; locally changed/overridden files under `/etc/ufw`; dynamically changed rules (for some reason) ought to be under `/run` (I just have a lock file there). The exception to the usual configuration is `/lib/ufw` which should also have some rules in it, but just has a startup script for `ufw`.

Comment: The way `/etc` overrides what is on `/run` which overrides what is on `/lib` (which is usually a symlink to `/usr/share`) is pretty consistent among _most_ configurations in Debian & Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16 and up user firewall rules are stored in `/etc/ufw/user.rules` and `/etc/ufw/user6.rules`. Overall all UFW rules and configs located in `/etc/ufw`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of September 2021, you can find all files and configuration of what is called the **UFS Framework** using [`man ufw-framework`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/ufw-framework.8.html). It describes in detail where each file goes, what it does, and how the system works together to launch the `ufw` framework at boot time.

This is valid for at least Ubuntu 22.04 and Debian 11 (Debian has an older version of the `man` page installed by default, but saying essentially the same).